# Можно ли хранить объекты разных классов (производных одного абстрактного класса) в одном массиве или списке?

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

Допустим имеется один абстрактный класс: `Word` - от него производим два класса: `Noun` и `Verb`. Тут сталкиваемся с вопросом: как хранить объекты этих классов? Создавать для каждого класса отдельный массив для храниения или есть вариант как их хранить в одном месте?

Comment: Можно. Очевидно, речь идет об указателях на объекты.

Comment: @Igor не понял про 4 символа...

Comment: Система не позволяет слишком короткие комментарии.

Comment: @Igor и как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно такое делают, храня в массиве либо ссылки (`std::reference_wrapper<Word>`, например) — но тогда надо куда-то складывать сами объекты, либо указатели (`std::unique_ptr<Word>`, в частности; `Word *` вряд ли имеет смысл).

Если хочется массив ссылок, два варианта, в принципе:

I. Положить рядом массив указателей, куда эти ссылки ссылаются.

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Word>> words;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Word>> library;
```

и тщательно вручную следить за соответствием массивов друг другу.

II. Либо сделать собственный боксинг:

```
template<typename T> struct Box: public std::unique_ptr<T> {
     using std::unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr;
     operator T &() const { return **this; }
};
std::vector<Box<Word>> words;
words.push_back(std::make_unique<Noun>("мама"));
```

(Пример простой реализации, ни на что не претендующий.)

Ну вот самый простой пример:

```
$ cat word.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct Word {
    virtual int value() const = 0;
    virtual ~Word() = default;
};

struct Noun: Word { int value() const { return 42; }};
struct Verb: Word { int value() const { return 31416; }};

template<typename T> struct Box: std::unique_ptr<T> {
    using std::unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr;
    operator T &() const { return **this; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Box<Word>> v;
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<Noun>());
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<Verb>());
    for(Word const &w: v) std::cout << w.value() << std::endl;
}
```

И если запустить, получится:

```
$ g++ word.cpp && ./a.exe
42
31416
```

Comment: Вообще-то я еще в вопросе указал, что меня интересует именно: "куда их складывать"

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch См. отредактированный.

Comment: прошу прощения, но все не могу понять куда таки складывать сами объекты?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Ну вот примерно как я добавил. :)

Comment: ага, понятно, спс

Comment: Не нужно наследоваться от unique_ptr. У него нет виртуального деструктора.

Comment: @KoVadim Во-первых, я специально указал: "ни на что не претендующий". Во-вторых, действительно, нет, и?

Comment: Я бы просто использовать unique_ptr - куда лучше и понятее. Да, в этом примере наверно ничего не будет. Но отсутствие виртаульно деструктора - это UB. А если в коде есть UB, то теоретически компилятор может сделать все, что угодно, так как имеет право.

Comment: Ну да, можно это сделать member variable, надо вручную профорвардить конструкторы, разница небольшая. Насчет UB — да, в принципе, может возникнуть, если например хранить боксы в std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> *>, надо будет где-то повесить табличку, чтобы так не делали. Вообще, я просто привел идею довольно специализированного типа, который мы уже слишком долго обсуждаем.

Comment: @KoVadim: Где тут UB??? UB при таком наследовании возникнет только в том случае, если сделать полиморфное удаление такого объекта. В данном случае никакого полиморфного удаления нет. И никакого UB нет тоже. Правило "Не нужно наследоваться от ... нет виртуального деструктора" из классического ООП неприменимо в общем случае. Наследоваться можно и нужно. Никакого UB тут нет.

Comment: "Но отсутствие виртаульно деструктора - это UB." - такого правила в С++ нет и никогда не было.

Comment: 8.3.5 пункт 3 + правило Мерфи:)

Comment: а это  using std::unique_ptr<T>::unique_ptr;  для чего?..

Comment: Это конструктор. :-)

Comment: @KoVadim: Здесь нет никакого "правила Мерфи". Во-первых, применение `delete` к тому, что никогда не выделялось `new` - само по себе уже UB, вне зависимости от наличия виртуального деструктора. Во-вторых, наследование от классов без виртуального деструктора - устойчивая и широко применяющаяся идиома в шаблонном метапрограммировании в С++. См. хотя бы идиомы CRTP или mix-ins. Без этого не обойтись. Правило про "нельзя наследоваться от класса без виртуального деструктора" умерло где-то давно в начале 00-х. Такого правила давно уже нет.

Comment: Я вот чего не понимаю: Зачем вообще делать `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Word>> words;`, если одного `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Word>> library;` достаточно?

Comment: потому что может:) красиво же  (а по факту бессмыслено).

Comment: @bipll не подскажете где почитать про боксинг? Впервые встречаю подобную конструкцию - много вопросов. И, заодно, не подскажете, почему `operator T &()` а не `T operator &()`?

Comment: Это просто оператор приведения типа. Конструкция самая обычная, я просто взял `unique_ptr` и добавил к нему неявное преобразование в ссылку на объект. Boxed object — это почти все значения в языках с reference semantics (Java, все динамические и т.п.).

Comment: @bipll а, понятно, совсем забыл про оператор приведения типа! Спс!

Answer (score 1):

Просто *объекты* хранить не стоит - сработает *срезка*.

Храните указатели (или интеллектуальные указатели) на абстрактный класс, и все будет отлично работать.

Comment: Тобишь кроме как создавать два отдельных массива вариантов нет?

Comment: Ну я же написал - один массив, но указателей. Вы КАК планируете создавать объекты? Если динамически - вообще идеально подходит. Если статически - сохраняйте в массиве указатели на `Word`, только тогда не удаляйте их, только и всего... Покажите, как бы вы **хотели**, чтобы выглядел ваш код - тогда можно будет подсказать точнее...

Answer (score 1):

Для хранения иерархически связанных типов можно использовать массив указателей на базовый класс. А чтобы не заморачиваться с низкоуровневыми конструкциями, вполне подойдет `std::vector`, параметризованный типом умного указателя `std::unique_ptr`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Word {
    virtual ~Word() = 0;
};

Word::~Word() {};

struct Noun : Word { };
struct Verb : Word { };

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Word>> v;
    v.push_back(make_unique<Noun>());
    v.push_back(make_unique<Verb>());
}
```

[Проверка компилируемости](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uTYU2DNvG4FujBta).